# Cannot access build on linux server

Tags: javascript, linux, reactjs

I have a react project and I have deployed it to a Linux server and I am not able to access the project.

I have deployed my react app on a Linux server and I have created a production build using "sudo npm run build" and try running the build file "serve -s build" and it gives the remote URL using which I can access my app. But when I try to hit the URL, I am not able to load anything.

I want to know why this is happening? 
I created a sample project and tried to build it but it also had the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to pass the IP of the server and I was able to access the application

Answer (score 0):

What `serve -s build` is providing you are the address to access it from localhost, and the address to access it from other computers on the same network as the linux machine.

```
   ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                                                  │
   │   Serving!                                       │
   │                                                  │
   │   - Local:            http://localhost:5000      │
   │   - On Your Network:  http://192.168.x.x:5000    │
   │                                                  │
   └──────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

If your machine is not on the same network as the linux machine then that second link will not work for you locally.

Comment: The server IP is 10.x.x.x and the local machine's IP is 192.x.x.x.
How should I be able to access the app then?
I have opened the required port on the server as well. But still, I cannot access it

Comment: 10.0.0.0/8 is a private block of IP addresses just like 192.168.0.0/16. There probably is another public IP.